# How can the Excel add-in be made to open Web page in Chrome browser?

Tags: excel, office365, office-js, office-addins

The Excel add-in opens a new browser page and uses IE only. The default Web browser in Windows is set to Chrome.
However, whenever the new Web page opens through the add-in, IE is used ignoring the default browser setting in Windows.
This issue is seen only in the Excel add-in. Others work fine by using the default browser.
How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

For office add-in using windows, Microsoft locks it down to IE.  documentation is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins

Comment: Thanks for the reply and link.Microsoft has stated that window.open can be used and will open it in the default browser. However, that window [that opens in default browser] will not be able to communicate back with the add-in.

There are posts saying that window.open does not work. We are trying to submit a form to a URL, so it's a bit more complex than just opening a link in a browser. We need to test this.